# PHP heavy task scheduling

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin for WordPress that fetches data from a remote website using PHP and displays it on the web page. **It takes about 2-5 seconds to fetch this data**.

The plugin has its own caching system, which fetches and stores new data on fixed time intervals.

The problem is that the task scheduler is based on visitors, so if enough time has passed, there would be a certain visitor that would have to wait for 2-5 seconds for the data to be fetched and cached in the database. How can this be avoided?

- Using Wordpress' built in task scheduler is not a solution, since it operates the same way as the caching system.
- PHP Cron job is not a solution either, since it is dependent on the hosting.

**How can I schedule a time consuming task to run behind the scene without affecting page load times**?
Note that this is a WordPress plugin, so the solution should not be platform dependent

Comment: Add an AJAX call to a refresh.php (or whatever you want to call it) to refresh data in the background? Or, if you have shell access on the web site: Run a cronjob that fetches the new data.

Comment: @ccKep this sounds like a good idea. What if the user doesn't stay on the page for 5 seconds, will it still complete the AJAX call on the server?

Comment: I don't know if apache (or whatever httpd you're using) kills the thread if the connection closes or if php (either the module or the invoked cli) are allowed to finish. In case they aren't: Load your data to temporary files first and just move them at the end of your script so you know they're all complete.

Comment: @ccKep can you please elaborate? Keep in mind that this is a WordPress plugin, and that I have no control over the user's settings. This might be a good answer to this question.

Comment: Could you post some snippets of your current data-fetching code? (Like opening the connection, reading data, closing the connection and saving it) That way maybe I can post something that actually helps you. I'm not too familiar with wordpress plugins though, hence my suggestions until now were general PHP practice when it comes to fetching data.

Comment: @ccKep you answer can be in general PHP practices, that's fine. I'm just looking for the general concept of how to achieve this using AJAX and temporary files as you have suggested.

Comment: Assuming you want to make sure that **all** your cached files are from the same pull: Download all your files to some temporary folder (eg. `tmp_fetch/...` and when all your files are downloaded (at the end of the script) delete(`unlink()`) the original data directory and `rename()` the tmpdir. It's hard to illustrate without knowing how you currently handle the update process. Edit: I was thinking of something along the lines of this for the PHP part: http://pastebin.com/CgEiARM8

Answer (score 0):

you can try cronjob if your hosting server compatible. Maybe you can make a special cache php script and put it on an iframe located your main page . If your plugin page comes after your index page , it would work

Comment: This is a problem since cron jobs are dependent on the hosting and i'm looking for a cross-platform solution

Comment: ok then make your own cronjob on an iframe .It wont be effective main page load time, just there will be a indicator message on browser "waiting for xxxx.php for response", after visitor navigate to another page , your iframed php page script keeps on working.It would be a bad solution , you can develop this idea. Maybe your plugin cacher page can control if the foreigner page content is changed or not. If its changed your cacher works else not. Maybe you can put this iframe on a plugin index page. Iframe wont effect to loading this page and you can say "Please wait content is loading".